# Allowing a smart contract to receive a swapped token

Tags: 0x

I'm currently building a dApp on the Polygon network, and I'd like my users to be able to initiate a swap to USDC through 0x, which in turn gets received by a function on the smart contract. Is this possible? And if yes, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you are expecting to be received the the function in your smart contract?

For example, are you looking for the response or the call data from the /quote request to be passed to your smart contract? or do you want to send some verification that the response has been signed to your smart contract? or something else?